# How to manage Android- to external device communication via web API?

Tags: android, multithreading, networking, xml-parsing, android-asynctask

I'm building a program which interfaces with a device which runs its own internal web server.  I communicate with the device via a web API.

Basically what happens is that a GUI is presented to the user, where the user can make certain modifications to the device.  These changes are communicated to the device, and results are returned through XML.  The device needs to converse with the program in the background more or less continually (say every 15s or so) to update certain values to the user.

My structure that I'm envisioning is something like this:

UI - Main  - Networking  - XML Parser.

I'm looking for advice on how to manage these.  I understand the UI thread should be separate to provide a smooth experience to users.  I also understand that the networking should be at least an asynchronous task.   I'm not so sure about how to handle their interaction, and make sure things are happening smoothly and effectively.

My idea is that Main will handle passing data around, telling the networker to send specific messages or changes, passing the returned XML to the parser, and then passing the parsed values to UI for handling.

I'm curious though for advice beyond that.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at creating a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) that is created with your `Activity`.  Without knowing the details of your plan, a `Service` looks like the optimal solution to perform all the heavy work.

UPDATE:

You could have the calls to web API run in a Service and, when needed, update the UI through an interface.  You would have to instruct the Service to run on its own thread, so thread safety is an issue, but less trouble in the long run than using an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I'm happy to share details.  What info would be usful?

Comment: @Nathaniel I don;t think I need amymore details.  I think a creating a service is the way to go.  I don;t think an AsyncTask is the way to go, it can be more trouble for long complex operations.  Services run in the background with out a UI.

Answer (score 0):

Have a thought about using Google C2DM.

In your case,

Pros -> Less battery use, coordinated network traffic, Don't have to run a continues service and doesn't have the potential of being killed when the device runs out of resources.

Cons -> You have to post the results manually back to your internal server, and server should know which request the device is replying to. Communication is disconnected and may not be real-time. Requires a google account on the device and Google market.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Madushan, I think this is something I would look at for other applications.  This specific project` is not a situation where google accounts are possible for device users.